# Bounded convex sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a non-negative bounded sequence such that
$$a_n \leq \frac{1}{2} \left(a_{n+1} +a_{n-1}\right)$$

Can we prove that $a_0 \geq a_1$?.

I tried to prove by contradiction, assume $a_0 < a_1$, then by moving the terms in the given inequality around, we get $a_n - a_{n-1} \leq a_{n+1} - a_n$.  So if $a_0 < a_1$, then $a_n$ is a bounded increasing sequence, so it is convergent. But after that, I don't know what I could do to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.Suppose that $a_1-a_0=t>0$.Then,as you said,we have $$a_{n+1}-a_{n}\ge a_{n}-a_{n-1}\ge...\ge a_1-a_0=t$$so $$a_{n+1}\ge a_{n}+t\ge a_{n-1}+2t\ge...\ge a_1+nt\ge a_0+(n+1)t.$$

Since $t>0$ we obtain that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$,which contradicts the fact that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded.

Hence $t\le 0$,meaning that $a_0\ge a_1$.Done.

**Note:** In the same manner we can prove that if $t<0$ the sequence $(a_n)$ is not bounded.Hence $t=0$,so the sequence is constant i.e. $a_0=a_1$.

Comment: Ah, that's a nice trick. Thank you.